# A better FizzBuzz

Tags: haskell, fizzbuzz

Is there any way I can make this FizzBuzz better?

```
toFizz :: Int -> String
toFizz x =
  case (mod x 3, mod x 5) of
      (0, 0) -> "FizzBuzz"
      (0, _) -> "Fizz"
      (_, 0) -> "Buzz"
      (_) -> show x

main :: IO()
main =
    mapM_ (print . toFizz) [1..100]
```

Comment: Do you want to tweak this implementation or are you looking for a "better" implementation?  If so, how do you define better?  Readability?  Efficiency?  Idiom?

Comment: @itsbruce Mainly compactness and efficiency, I suppose "better" IS very subjective but I'm open to any kinds of improvements, everything is worth consideration!

Comment: OK, have added a pointer to how more efficient implementations might be considered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, I can suggest two improvements:

One is rewriting toFizz in a more explicit manner:

```
toFizz :: Int -> String
toFizz x
  | x `mod` 15 == 0 = "FizzBuzz"
  | x `mod` 3 == 0 = "Fizz"
  | x `mod` 5 == 0 = "Buzz"
  | otherwise = show x
```

Your pattern match with (mod 3, mod 5) puzzled me a fair bit. Also use

```
x `mod` y
```

Instead of:

```
mod x y
```

for readability.

`main` can be written to avoid all those quotes making output nicer:

```
main :: IO()
main = putStrLn $ unlines $ map toFizz [1..100]
```

Comment: In my original code, the case statement caches the `mod x 3` and `mod x 5` and make it so that it does not have to check `mod x 15` also, so I would argue that it's the better of the two.

Comment: @TristanMcPherson thanks for commeting. Beware of premature optimization. A program to print 100 numbers needs not to be fast.

Comment: @Caridorc of course not, but the question was for the BEST fizzbuzz ;), even if it's just fizzbuzz, also why is it something to beware of?

Comment: @TristanMcPherson this is a very big concept, no way to discuss it all in comments here. It is just that you should always balance readability and optimizations, and it is not always easy to do so.

Comment: This version is quadratic in the number of primes you consider (and you have to repeat yourself). See e.g. [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/2441kp/fizzbuzz_in_haskell_by_embedding_a_dsl/) for linear versions.

Comment: @TristanMcPherson Haskell's nature makes premature optimisation particularly bad.  Always start with the most expressive solution you can think up.  Sometimes (thanks to laziness), that is even the most efficient; it's often more efficient than prematurely optimised, over-complicated solutions.  Then, as you optimise, look for common patterns in your optimisations; go back and generalise them.  The more complex your changes become, the more likely it is that you should rethink your approach.

Comment: @gallais to clarify your rather opaque comment, the code _size_ will grow _"geometrically"_ (quoting from that reddit thread, thanks for the link!) if you add more factors into consideration (here we have just 2 of them -- 3 and 5).

Answer (score 4):

As gallais has mentioned, the cost of your calculations increases as x increases.

I'm always struck by how few people, when faced with fizzBuzz or similar challenges (like finding the first `n` numbers which are divisible by 3 and/or 5), realise there is no need to work backwards from x to the original primes.  It's much more efficient to work *forwards*.  After all, you know the starting primes, 3 and 5.  One might consider, for example, generating a map where the keys are the numbers 1 to 100 (or x to y) and the value is `show`.  Then iterate over the multiples of 3 between x and y, replacing the value with `const "fizz"` and so on.  Then iterate over the keys of the map in order, applying the value (a function) to the key.  There are smarter (and more efficient) ways to work forwards, but it illustrates the principle.

Here's a relatively naive forwards-iterating implementation of `toFizzBuzz` I just thought up.

```
fizz :: Int -> String
fizz = const "fizz"

buzz :: Int -> String
buzz = const "buzz"

fizzbuzz :: Int -> String
fizzbuzz = const "fizzbuzz"

fizzbuzzFuncs =  cycle [show, show, fizz, show, buzz, fizz, show, show, fizz, buzz, show, fizz, show, show, fizzbuzz]

toFizzBuzz :: Int -> Int -> [String]
toFizzBuzz start count =
    let offsetFuncs = drop (mod (start - 1) 15) fizzbuzzFuncs
    in take count $ zipWith ($) offsetFuncs [start..]
```

Note that it can work from any starting point (even negative n) for any range, within the limits imposed by `Int`.  Now, there are smarter ways to do this kind of thing (and certainly more idiomatic and generalised), but that example is still more efficient than 99% of the fizzBuzz attempts I see,  Only does any arithmetic *once*.

Work forwards, not backwards.  Don't go looking expensively for things you can easily generate.

Challenge: consider a solution using `unfoldr`

Comment: Very very interesting. I suppose I've been tainted by seeing the generic implementation to think outside the box!

Comment: I think [you've misunderstood](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/104322/a-better-fizzbuzz#comment191359_104327) that comment by gallais. the code _size_ is what's exploding (_if_ we'd add more factors for it to handle); yours will too - in the hand-written list's length, which must contain `lcm(all_factors)` entries. you can remedy this by defining a list-generating code in the spirit of that reddit thread. the OP code's _run time_ is certainly linear - it performs no more than 1 test for each factor (here there's just two of them),  per each `x`.

Comment: (contd.) But the idea of precalculating a rolling wheel is indeed nice. You could even generate that list without doing any divisibility tests too, by generating and merging the lists of multiples for each factor, for a fully generative solution! This will offset the cost of initial tests with the cost of merging those separate lists into one.

Comment: What you mention your second comment is precisely what I would do to generalise this, yes.

Comment: @WillNess the rolling wheel is, in a simple case like this, much more expressive and efficient than some kind of monadic/ADT iteration.  But generating the wheel from the smaller components would be rather less hacky ;)

Comment: okay, so taking your idea and running with it, I got `fzbz = zipWith (flip ($)) [1..] . map (\s-> if null s then show else const s) 
 . foldr1 (zipWith (++))
 . map (\(d,s) -> tail . cycle $ s : replicate (d-1) "")
 $ zip [1,3,5] ["","fizz","buzz"]`. an altogether nice result.